# Recursive CTE - consolidate start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
row_num customer_status    effective_from_datetime
------- ------------------ -----------------------
1       Active             2011-01-01
2       Active             2011-01-02
3       Active             2011-01-03
4       Suspended          2011-01-04
5       Suspended          2011-01-05
6       Active             2011-01-06
```

And am trying to achieve the following result whereby consecutive rows with the same status are merged into one row with an effective from and to date range:

```
customer_status effective_from_datetime effective_to_datetime
--------------- ----------------------- ---------------------
Active          2011-01-01              2011-01-04
Suspended       2011-01-04              2011-01-06
Active          2011-01-06              NULL
```

I can get a recursive CTE to output the correct effective_to_datetime based on the next row, but am having trouble merging the ranges.

Code to generate sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
row_num INT IDENTITY(1,1),
customer_status VARCHAR(10),
effective_from_datetime DATE
)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES 
('Active','2011-01-01')
,('Active','2011-01-02')
,('Active','2011-01-03')
,('Suspended','2011-01-04')
,('Suspended','2011-01-05')
,('Active','2011-01-06')
```

Comment: Oh, and I don't want to use a cursor or loop because the plan is to use this logic in a view.

Comment: What if you don't have an entry for a date? Should that be regarded as a gap in the sequence? e.g. suppose the `('Active','2011-01-02')` row wasn't there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**  SQL updated as per comment.

```
WITH
  group_assigned_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_status ORDER BY effective_from_date) AS status_sequence_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                             ORDER BY effective_from_date) AS sequence_id,
    customer_status,
    effective_from_date
  FROM
    your_table
)
,
  grouped_data AS
(
  SELECT
    customer_status,
    MIN(effective_from_date)   AS min_effective_from_date,
    MAX(effective_from_date)   AS max_effective_from_date
  FROM
    group_assigned_data
  GROUP BY
    customer_status,
    sequence_id - status_sequence_id
)
SELECT
  [current].customer_status,
  [current].min_effective_from_date       AS effective_from,
  [next].min_effective_from_date          AS effective_to
FROM
  grouped_data   AS [current]
LEFT JOIN
  grouped_data   AS [next]
    ON [current].max_effective_from_date = [next].min_effective_from_date + 1
ORDER BY
  [current].min_effective_from_date
```

This isn't recursive, but that's possibly a good thing.

It doesn't deal with gaps in your data.  To deal with that you could create a calendar table, with every relevant date, and join on that to fill missing dates with 'unknown' status, and then run the query against that.  (Infact you cate do it it a CTE that is used by the CTE above).

At present...
- If row 2 was missing, it would not change the result
- If row 3 was missing, the end_date of the first row would change

Different behaviour can be determined by preparing your data, or other methods.  We'd need to know the business logic you need though.

If any one date can have multiple status entries, you need to define what logic you want it to follow.  At present the behaviour is undefined, but you could correct that as simply as adding `customer_status` to the `ORDER BY` portions of ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: The one problem I see (which I think makes the solution completely different) - the effective_to_datetime should be equal to the effective_from_datetime of the subsequent row.

Comment: @shakedown7 - That's the "gap" situation I referred to.  If you have gaps that the easiest solution is to LEFT JOIN on to a calendar table to fill in the gaps.  This will cause three types of group to appear, one of which relates to your gaps, and you can give a name or choose to filter out afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Dems, I dont think it's the same as the "gap" situation though. The effective_to_datetime should not be the MAX(effective_from_datetime) for that grouping - it needs to be the MIN(effective_from_datetime) of the next group. ie. The "Active" row should have an effective_to_datetime of 2011-01-04 - which is the start date of the "Suspended" row (as opposed to 2011-01-03).

Comment: @shakedown7 - Oh, I get ya.  You need to LEFT JOIN the results on themselves then.  I'll add an example.